# Why we are not using a pointer in instantiating the entity object in the code given below of C++?

Tags: c++, instantiation

In the main function in this code what does this (ScopedPtr ent = new Entity()) mean
Why we are not using (ScopedPtr*) as per **C++ instantiating style**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Created Entity!" << std::endl;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Print" << std::endl;
    }
    
};

class ScopedPtr
{
private:
    Entity* m_Ptr;
public:
    ScopedPtr( Entity* ptr) 
        : m_Ptr(ptr)
    {}

    /*ScopedPtr()
    {   
        std::cout << "Hello"; 
    }*/

    ~ScopedPtr()
    {
        std::cout << "Deleted Pointer";
        delete m_Ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        ScopedPtr ent = new Entity();
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

And why the ScopedPtr(Entity Constructor) Didn't take a Entity* parameter and the code ran successfully.

Comment: the constructor is `ScopedPtr( Entity* ptr)`. It does have an `Entity*` parameter

Comment: read about the keyword `explicit`

Comment: I am Talking about `ScopedPtr ent = new Entity()` in this code it didn't take a actual parameter in the main function.

Answer (score 4):

```
ScopedPtr ent = new Entity();
```

The right-hand-side is a value of type `Entity*`, regardless of the details.  So it could be written as

```
Entity* t = new Entity();  // doesn't matter what it's = to, just note its type.
ScopedPtr ent = t;
```

Now you have a variable definition `T x = y;` where `y` is not of type `T`.  So, it implicitly converts to the correct type, and this is really

```
ScopedPtr ent = ScopedPtr(t);
```

The `=` here is initialization not assignment, so `ent` is initialized with that (converted) right-hand-side.

Answer (score 1):

> Why we are not using `(ScopedPtr*)` as per C++ instantiating style

Because `new` is **not required** to create objects. The **whole point** of `ScopedPtr` is to tie the lifetime of an object with dynamic storage duration ("on the heap") to another with automatic storage duration ("on the stack")